# Confluent.Schema.Registry .NET Avro Deserialization Error

Tags: .net-core, client, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I currently have a netcore 2.0 console application that produces Avro messages, however when I attempt to consume them, the deserializer is fails when attempting to retrieve the schema from the schema registry due to a missing client method (See exception).

```
"Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.String> Confluent.SchemaRegistry.ISchemaRegistryClient.GetSchemaAsync(Int32)'."
```

The following Nuget packages have been installed:

- Confluent.Kafka v1.4.0
- Confluent.SchemaRegistry v1.4.0
- Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes v1.3.0
- Confluent.Apache.Avro v1.7.7.7

Just wondering if anyone has run into this particular problem before?

Answer (score 1):

After too many days spent trying to resolve this issue, I finally found a posting that indicated that Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes v1.3.0 is not compatible with Confluent.SchemaRegistry 1.4.0. Downgrading Confluent.SchemaRegistry to 1.3.0 resolves the problem.

That being said, it would be nice it the dependency requirements for the nuget packages were enforced.